# SharePoint getbytitle rest api returns duplicate Id property

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to get all folders for a SharePoint list using below REST api

> _api/web/lists/getbytitle(<list_name)/items?$filter=FSObjType eq 1&$select=ID,FileLeafRef,FileRef

the return JSON contains duplicate ID property with same value:

```
{
    "value": [
      {
        "Id": 6,
        "FileLeafRef": "Folder 1",
        "ID": 6,
        "FileRef": "/sites/abc/pqr/Folder 1"
      },
      {
        "Id": 16,
        "FileLeafRef": "Folder 2",
        "ID": 16,
        "FileRef": "/sites/abc/pqr/Folder 2"
      }
      ]
}
```

I want to parse this JSON in power automate where i am getting error due to duplicate ID property

Thanks

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove ID in select . I haven't tried it but just a guess.

_api/web/lists/getbytitle(<list_name)/items?$filter=FSObjType eq 1&$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef